# Automatic creation of Vimeo video previews for use in wordpress archive.php

Tags: php, wordpress, video, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to find a method of automatically making 3-7 sec long previews of my video + films for use in a WordPress video wall gallery in such as what's found here: https://scale.la/test.html

Currently I have to save these cut down and export each file as a <1mb MP4 and embed using  tags by hand. They then link to pages that have the Vimeo player embedded [using Vimeotheque, a WP plugin for automatic Vimeo posting]. When displaying an archive of posts / Vimeo videos, the previews are based on the Preview Thumbnail.

What I would like to do is replace that Thumbnail with a video thumbnail like my test — that is extracted from the longer form video already on Vimeo.

Are there any provisions to do this with current Vimeo tools?

Thanks,

Todd

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @flomei I am doing it by hand [like the example] and this is a very tedious process that I would like to automate.

Comment: I could tell you how I would do it, but that would probably not be very useful. That's why you should think about how you could do this in general, look into the options and then ask again once you have a general idea of how everything comes together. Also you can then ask specific questions where people will be able to help you in detail.